# How do I recall Today's Ooblets list?

Tags: ooblets

At the start of each day, the player sees a daily Today's Ooblets bulletin showing which ooblets are available that day and where. Is there some place to revisit this "ooblets of the day" view after the day begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can view the ooblets in **Badgetown** via the map to the left of Meed's Seeds shop. You can select the gray dots to see where the ooblets are located but it won't specify their rarity.

You can also take a **screenshot** of the initial ooblet screen ([Steam Deck](https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-the-steam-deck), [Nintendo Switch](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22343/%7E/how-to-capture-and-view-screenshots), [Xbox](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/friends-social-activity/share-socialize/capture-game-clips-and-screenshots)).